# Determining size of the drive (no file system on the drive) Win7

Tags: winapi

The IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY [example code of Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives the expected [results](http://szte-wsn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/szte-wsn/private/ali/drive_size/output.txt?revision=2946&view=markup) for the hard disk.

The SD card is drive F: and has no file system. The card was previously written by an 8 bit microcontroller and file system is out of the question. In the windows explorer, the SD card size is displayed correctly as 1886 MB. However when I run the program I get 0.01 GB.

**Is the example code correct?** I slightly changed the original code, the changed one is [here](http://szte-wsn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/szte-wsn/private/ali/drive_size/main.c?revision=2945&view=markup).

**Can it be an issue with Mingw?** I doubt, it works fine for the hard disk. It is mingw32 gcc 4.6.1 on WinXP SP2. The resulting program is run on Win7. I am using Linux and I have very limited access to native Win7.

**How can I figure out the size of the SD card without file system?**

Comment: Its usually printed on the card

Comment: @littleadv I have to get the size programatically, in a C code.

Comment: The code you linked requires a Master Boot Record on the drive.  Sure sounds like you don't have one.  Next step down, perhaps, is IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO

Comment: Way too many irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Hans Passant, the [IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should be passed to `DeviceIoControl`.

Everything works fine if the `CreateFile` [remarks concerning physical disks and volumes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_disks_and_volumes) are followed. The resulting code is [here](http://szte-wsn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/szte-wsn/private/ali/win32_drive_size/main.cpp?revision=2948&view=markup).